# Hipchat4 freezes working system

Tags: system

Hipchat4 was released last week and I installed the new version, but when I use it for 4-5 minutes my Ubuntu desktop stops working and I can't do anything except shut it down.

How can I fix this issue?
One thing -- I have an old version of Hipchat (hipchat1) on my system. Could having both versions be causing my problem?

Comment: It simply crashes a lot on me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where about once a day Hipchat4 would freeze my system, but I could still remote into my system and if I killed the Hipchat4 process then my system would work again.

What seems to be working for me to prevent this issue is to run Hipchat4 out of the command line with the `--disable-gpu` option.